# Is there a closed form solution to $y \frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking for a closed-form solution to the differential equation

$$y \frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x. $$

This arises in trying to plot the field lines from a uniformly magnetized conical shell.

Comment: MathJax tip:  use curly braces around the argument of the square root

Comment: *Hint*: Let $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and you get a easy homogeneous DE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2+1}$

Let $y=tx$.

$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=t+x\frac{dt}{dx}$

$\implies t+x\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{t} +\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+1}$

$\implies \frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dt}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+1} +\frac{1}{t}-t}$

Integrating on both sides,

$\ln(x)+c=\int \frac{tdt}{1-t^2+\sqrt{1+t^2}}$

Let $1+t^2=z^2\implies zdz=tdt$

$\implies \ln(|x|)+c=\int \frac{zdz}{1-(z^2-1)+z}$

$\implies \ln(|x|)+c=\int \frac{zdz}{2+z-z^2}=\frac{-1}{2}\left ( \int \frac{(2z-1)dz}{z^2-z-2}+\int \frac{dz}{z^2-z-2} \right)$

$\implies \ln(|x|)+c=\frac{-1}{2} \left( \ln(|z^2-z-2| )+\frac{1}{3}\ln\left(\frac{|2-z|}{|z+1|}\right)\right)$

$\implies c|x|=|z^2-z-2|^{\frac{-1}{2}}\left(\frac{|2-z|}{|1+z|}\right)^{\frac{-1}{6}}$

Where $z=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}$.

Comment: thanks, this looks useful.  In trying to make some plots, I find that the first factor is real only for z>2 and the second factor is real only for z<2.  Should I be considering complex roots?

Comment: Which one is the first and which is the second factor you are talking about?

Comment: sorry - ignore - I missed the absolute value sign!

Comment: Thank you - that answer has proven to be exceedingly helpful!

Comment: You're welcome. How did it help?

Comment: I have a confession: I missed a minus sign on the left side of my equation and that leads to an easier solution. But what I did find valuable in your approach was looking out for constructions like xdy/dx + y = d(xy)/x and x + ydy/dx = (1/2)d(x^2+y^2)/dx in finding solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, take for example $y(x) = \sqrt{3}\, x$